# What is a bottleneck in pandas.read_csv: CPU vs Storage

Tags: python, pandas, hardware, data-science

What is actually a bottleneck of reading csv file with pandas.read_csv()?

Is it CPU or Storage reading speed limitations?

How much speed increase can be obtained if use SSD instead of HDD?

To be more specific, let's consider the following configuration (the current cheapest server from Hetzner):

```
Intel® Core™ i7-6700 Quad-Core Skylake
32 GB DDR4 RAM
2Tb HDD SATA 6 Gb/s 7200 rpm Enterprise Class Software RAID 1 
or
500Gb SSD SATA 6 Gb/s Software RAID 1
```

Comment: CPU and memory IO will always be faster than disk IO. Whether SSD will help depends on how much data you read from disk, and how often.

Comment: Read your typical CSV file in a loop e.g. 10000 times and check the CPU usage. If it is less than 100%, IO is your bottleneck

Comment: @match I mean you need to spend CPU time for csv parsing

Comment: @code_onkel, good idea. i'll maybe do it on weekend

Comment: @AlexanderLedovsky Make sure that the kernel caching does not bias your results https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system (assuming you are on *nix)

Comment: Actually, i'm selecting a server for data science with HDD versus SSD and try to understand whether HDD will affect much to my work performance.

Comment: @code_onkel thx!

Comment: Parsing the CSV is extremely unlikely to take a significant period of time compared to reading it (assuming you mean e.g. turning csv into a dict, rather than say doing complex matsh on its values. Out of interest, take a look at https://computers-are-fast.github.io/